# Is there any way to send email with attachment in windows phone

Tags: c#, email, windows-phone-7.1

Its really frustating that EmailComposeTask doesn't have any way to send attachments. I googled this and found MailMessage dll. I don't know whether it is secure or not because user gonna send his password. 
Now  I am thinking tot build my own service, send data from phone to service, and service will use smtp to send email with attachment.
Now I want to ask, Am I right? What kind of service I use?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about security concerns of MailMesssage.dll.
However, if you wish to send transactional EMails, then there are few services available. In such a case, you will not be required to create your own service. The popular one's are:

- [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com)
- Mandrill by MailChimp
- MailGun by Rackspace

All services provide free tier and may be helpful, if you need to send, less EMails. Moreover, besides `SMTP`, these services provide `Web APIs`, so you can send mails using `REST` interface.